# Python Mechanize select a form with no name

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I am attempting to have mechanize select a form from a page, but the form in question has no "name" attribute in the html. What should I do? when I try to use

```
br.select_form(name = "")
```

I get errors that no form is declared with that name, and the function requires a name input. There is only one form on the page, is there some other way I can select that form?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

to select the first form

In Mechanize [source](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/b1d786906946f0193051920a7c716b339bd7bf95/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L462),

```
def select_form(self, name=None, predicate=None, <b>nr=None</b>):
    """
    ...
    nr, if supplied, is the sequence number of the form (where 0 is the
    first).
    """
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for my instance with only one form. Just out of curiosity, how do you think it could be done with many forms? Either all unnamed or some named and others unnamed?

Comment: @mvid, yeah, a document could have many forms and names are optional too, and mechanize should be no problem with that.

Comment: where we can get predicate value from form ?

Comment: @Gunslinger_: predicate is a function that takes the form and returns True or False whether to select it or not

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute code for multiple forms no matter what their name is, you can loop over every form letting your script knowing which form will work next.

```
currentForm = 0
for form in br.forms(): # Iterate over the forms
        br.select_form(nr = currentForm) # Select the form
        '''
        The code you want to run for every form
        '''
        currentForm += 1 # Add 1 to the current working form so the script knows what form is working next
```