# How do I submit a form with Mechanize if there is no `SubmitControl`

Tags: python, forms, submit, mechanize

I have [this](https://m.fanfiction.net/m/review.php?storyid=9652709&chapter=1&storytextid=35686233) page and I am trying to fill out the form, and then submit the review, but when I use

```
for i in br.forms():
    print i
```

I get

```
<storytextid=35686233 application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<TextControl(name=)
<HiddenControl(name_default=Name:) (readonly)>
<TextareaControl(review=Please ignore this message)>
<HiddenControl(review_default=Type your review here.) (readonly)>
<IgnoreControl(action=<None>)>
<HiddenControl(storyid=9652709) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(chapter=1) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(storytextid=35686233) (readonly)>>
```

notice the absence of a `SubmitControl` like in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582580/python-mechanize-select-a-form-with-no-name)

```
<HiddenControl(<None>=2582580) (readonly)>
<TextareaControl(post-text=)>
<HiddenControl(fkey=47c5f6845374787ee763de7fbcf2ec24) (readonly)>
<TextControl(author=)>
<HiddenControl(manual-openid=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(use-facebook=false) (readonly)>
<IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
<TextControl(display-name=)>
<TextControl(m-address=)>
<TextControl(display-name=)>
<TextControl(m-address=)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Post Your Answer) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(legalLinksShown=1) (readonly)>>
```

so when I run

```
br.submit()
```

nothing happens, no errors, it seems to go through fine, but the review doesn't show up.
and when I run

```
br.title()
```

it returns `None`

how do I submit a form with no `SubmitControl`?

Comment: the botton Post Review is calling a Javascript function, so it's not going to be on the form.

Comment: I know that, that's why I asked this question, I ended up using a different module. Which is q

Comment: Splinter, which can run JavaScript