# Python mechanize - filling a form with no name and 'no form matching nr 0'

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to fill out a very simple form that lacks a name. I need to feed some numbers into three fields and acquire the output. The question of how to fill a form with no defined name has been answered a number of times (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020117/mechanize-mechanize-formnotfounderror-no-form-matching-name-q) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582580/python-mechanize-select-a-form-with-no-name)), but the solutions offered do not work for me. If I run my script:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open( "http://bessel.vlbi-astrometry.org/bayesian" )

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form[ 'l' ] = 30.
br.form[ 'b' ] = 0.1
br.form[ 'vlsr' ] = 100.

response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Fill_webform_noname_nonumber.py", line 6, in <module>
    br.select_form(nr=0)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
```

In the other questions, the solution was either to select e.g. the first form if it has no name by:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

as I have already tried, or find the available forms by:

```
print [form for form in br.forms()]
```

In the latter case, I am simply returned with an empty list.

I'm obviously missing something. How can I submit this form?