# Python: Login a website with correct password but return bad 404

Tags: python

Need to login to this webpage but fail. The error return is 404 but I have enter the correct username and password.

```
import requests
import urllib2

session_requests = requests.session()
login_data = dict(name='john', password='abcdefg')
session_requests.post('https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html', data=login_data)
```

Is token is needed to login for this webpage? How to do if needed?

Comment: seems there is no post route defined for `login.html`. if you inspect network stats from your browser, you'll see that the filled form data is submitted to `do_login.html` with post method and also a few other parameters http://imgur.com/a/Udt8y

Comment: @marmeladze do you mean authenticity_token is what I miss? How shall I put it as input?

Comment: @marmeladze do you mean `https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html?use_https=1` shall be use?

Comment: no, i mean, first of all,  you should post to `https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/do_login.html?use_https=1`. second, you'll not able to login that way - because an authenticity token is generated for every request and you have no chance to replicate it. as you also see from screenshot, password is not submitted as it is - instead it is converted to a hashed string and set to `password_m`  and that one is posting to `do_login.html`

Comment: So it means I have no way to login using python?

Comment: of course there is a way. I'll post in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

1) It returns 404 because they have not set a `POST` route for `main_url/login.html` page.

2)Requests  package is not a good fit for simulating browser actions. Use [mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0 ')] #this is my info -))
br.set_handle_robots(False)br.open('https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html?use_https=1')
```

There are three forms on that page (just `print br.forms()`), and by default mechanize looks for form name. the login form has not any.

So select it by id ([credit goes to that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495313/mechanize-select-form-using-id))

```
br.select_form(predicate = lambda f: 'id' in f.attrs and f.attrs['id'] == 'sic_login_form_user_login')
# according to this post, forms can be selected by it order
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582592/4481312
# so br.select_form(nr=1) is ok and more readable
```

then fill the form

```
br.form['name']='foo'
br.form['password']='asdfags'
```

and finally submit it.

```
br.submit()
```

I've not installed mechanize package on my current machine, so I am not able to test the output/process.

Comment: Is `selenium` similar to `mechanize` that using a browser too to open? Also, what is `br.select_form(predicate = lambda f: 'id' in f.attrs and f.attrs['id'] == 'sic_login_form_user_login')` purpose?

Comment: it return `mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error`

Comment: 1. I've added an explanation for predicate. 2. Yes, selenium also might be an alternative - bu t I've not used it personally. 3. 500 error is not your fault, it is serverfault -))

Comment: How about the `'sic_login_header_password'`? and also `'sic_login_header_username'`? I do not understand where `'sic_login_form_user_login'` coming from?

Comment: you don't need them - if you have also selected their wrapper form. if you follow the code, after selecting the form, i've filled inputs according to their name.

Comment: 1. `print br.forms()` just show `<generator object __call__ at 0x7f6e1aef60f0>` 2. Then how you get `'sic_login_form_user_login' ` from? please explain further as I do not understand how it actually works. Could you please test on your side, because it always return `mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The answer as below. I would suggest using selenium as it can handle javacript, rendering and more like a human rather than like a robot that the website can reject it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html?use_https=1")
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("sic_login_header_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("sic_login_header_password")
print "find id done"
username.send_keys("name")
password.send_keys("password")
print "log in done"
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
```